# Retrieve a downloaded JSON file from a client device angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, json, angularjs, cordova

I am building an offline functionality for a Cordova app that I am developing and I have a php file that gets only the list of images and I have taken the JSON from it and saved in the client device through FILESYSYTEM API and when I tried to retrieve it using angularjs, I couldn't display the images, even though I can see the container of every one of the images. Do I have to parse it so that it an be displayed or what am I missing ?

```
{ $http({
        method: 'POST', // I have used the GET method as well
        url: 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/local_store/json1.json'
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.clientData = data;
    });
}
```

and here is how it is that I am trying to display it

```
{<img class="image_dir" ng-src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/local_store/{{image.image_dir}}">
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are assigning the data returned from the success function to the clientdata scope. However in your ng-src for the image you are not referencing clientscope anywhere. Im not sure how your JSON object is formatted but a possible solution could be

```
{<img class="image_dir" ng-src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/local_store/{{clientscope.image.image_dir}}">
}
```

I would `console.log(clientscope);` to see what it contains

Though Im not sure where this snippet of code resides since it looks like its wrapped in an object so it could be part of the JSON but if it is then the snippet is in the wrong format for JSON which could be another solution if it is.

Comment: I have just used a simple angular $http call and everything seems to work well and most of all,it works offline too